# Environment variables when running unshare

Tags: bash, environment-variables, namespace

Is there any namespace (process, user, etc) that isolates environment variables?

In case there is, what happens when you `unshare`? Do they get cloned? What happens if a process changes an existing variable?

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any namespace to isolate environment variables. They're already isolated and private to each process. Modifying an environment variable in a child process will NOT propagate to its parent.

Environment variables in Unix are just a bunch of strings stored in the address space of a process. When a process forks, its children will "inherit" a copy of them together with the whole address space, and when a program executes another (and replaces the entire content of the address space), they have to be passed explicitly as the `envp` argument to the `execve(2)` system call if they're to be preserved.

If you want to start a process with an *empty* environment, you can start it as

```
env - cmd ...
```

which will just call `execve("/path/to/cmd", ["cmd", ..., NULL], [NULL])`.

Or to run it with an environment containing just `FOO=bar`:

```
env - FOO=bar cmd ...
```

Both the namespace affecting system calls (`clone(2)`, `unshare(2)`, `setns(2)`) and command line utilities like `unshare(1)` do not consider or affect the environment in any special way.

---

Note: This is how it works in Unix, not some law of nature. On other systems like plan9 (where the concept the namespace originated, but where all namespaces are basically *mount* namespaces, since everything there is a file/system) the [environment](http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/3/env) is just a filesystem mounted by default on `/env` and, contrary to Unix, [*shared* by default](http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/2/fork) between the parent and the child.

Comment: Is this the same in Linux? Every time I start a process all that data is copied to the process memory? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it now, the initial variables, which i believed they were "global" (like in windows) they are actually not, and they are just written in some file. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: 1. For all intents and purposes, Linux is Unix. 2. Yes all that data is copied, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496943/308316) for some low level details. You may think of the environment strings as of "hidden" command line arguments -- which are automatically added to each command for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables in `bash` are only scoped to a particular instance of the shell, so there is no need to define separate namespaces for them.

You can see this clearly if you open two terminal windows at once (in a Desktop Environment). Create a new environment variable in one of them, e.g.:

```
TEST_VAR=34
```

It won't appear in the `bash` session in the other terminal window.

Comment: It is not `bash` specific.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the OP has applied the tag 'bash'

Comment: Yes I noticed. However it is still not specific to `bash`.

Comment: Thanks Both, this is very useful for me and helps me to understand  - When I start a new process, where are all those variables coming from?

Comment: I think I got it now, the initial variables, which i believed they were "global" (like in windows) they are actually not, and they are just written in some file